# "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is the code.

```
package t.t;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add, sub; 
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter+=1;
                display.setText("Your total is" +counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is" +counter);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the activity code

Comment: null pointer on line 32 in `StartingPoint.java`. you might use an object that has not yet been initialised.

Comment: i dont know why it doesnt let me edit

Comment: because u are a new user. please read the FAQ.

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: I'm sorry you got frustrated with this site. The policies, however, are in place for a good reason. Would you mind cleaning up your text and posting your original question?

Comment: In fact, also post the log you had before as well, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a null pointer exception:

02-06 10:57:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2622): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 10:57:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2622): at t.t.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:32)

The log tells you what the problem is and where it is happening: In this case the problem is occuring in StartingPoint.java in the class StartingPoint in the onCreate method at line 32.

Edit after seeing code:

So the problem is you're not setting Sub to anything. I think you meant to do that with this line:

```
   add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Change it to:

```
   sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

And then try again.

Comment: You look at line 32 and see what is null, and make it not be null.  Without seeing the code it is impossible for us to help fix it.

Comment: @user3280351  Thanks. Would you mark my answer as correct? Also mind cleaning up your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `counter` with:

```
int counter = 0;
```

You should always initialize your `int`s as they cannot be `null`. `Integer`s, yes...`int`s no.

---

EDIT: Apparently Java doesn't work the same as C++ when forgetting to initialize an int. This answer won't solve your issue, but initializing all variables is still good practice to pick up.

Comment: Actually Java will initialize int's to 0, and it wouldn't give an NPE.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I never actually ran into that issue since I've gotten into the habit of initializing when writing in C++. Differences between Debug and Release mode killed me when I first started in VS. Regardless of whether or not this will solve his problem (it won't), it's still good practice.

Comment: I hear ya. I'm from a C/C++ background myself so I still initialize things that way too.